# Is there a way to run logrotate of a specific application's logs only at times other than midnight?

Tags: cron, logrotate

I put the file I set in the "logrotate.d folder".

And I wanted to run the file only at 00:30 every day through "**crontab -e**".

However, when I checked the next day, it was executed at 00:00 and also at 00:30.

After searching and checking, I found out that cron.daily has logrotate set up, and logrotate is set to run at 00:00 by default.

So, it was executed at 00:00 and at 00:30 that I set, confirming that it was executed twice.

I tried to modify logrotate in cron.daily, but it seemed difficult to exclude only certain files because the system log was also set.

Is there a way to run logrotate only at certain times of the day?
I would be grateful if you let me know if there is!

Comment: Read `man logrotate logrotate.conf;man -a crontab`. Remove your file from `logrotate.d` directory, undo your "modify logrotate in cron.daily". You can easily set up your `00:30` `cron`job to rotate your logs using your own `logrotare.conf`. Let the system rotate its logs (but not your log) at `00:00`.

Comment: @waltinator / Does it still mean there is no logrotate file I have set up in the logrotare.conf folder?

Comment: From `man logrotate`: `logrotate [-dv] [-f|--force] [-s|--state file] config_file`, so you can have your logrotate configuration file anywhere. The `logrotate.d/` directory is used by multiple developers. It's easier and safer for a log-producing package to simply add its logrotation configuration as a file in `logrotate.d`. The other way involves each package developer figuring out how to parse the common `logrotate.conf`, so as to safely add their data.  You, as a single rotator,  do not need this complexity.  Use a simple, `mylogrotate.conf`. ..

Comment: @waltinator Thanks!